# Detect an island in a matrix, in C

Tags: c

Good evening everybody,

I am working on a program where, after a few steps, I am getting a matrix full of 0, 1, 2 and 3. In this one, I would like to know if there is an island of 2 surrounded by 3 (and the ubiquitous 1).

Like :

```
matrix=[[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
        [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
        [0,1,3,1,3,1,0,1],
        [1,0,1,2,1,0,1,0],
        [0,1,3,1,3,1,0,1],
        [1,0,1,2,1,0,1,0],
        [0,1,3,1,3,1,0,1],
        [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]]
```

Here, we can see that matrix[3][3] and matrix[5][3] are completely surrounded by 3 (and 1) so, I would like a function that could return this fact. I do not need to know in what position or if there is more than one island.

I am thinking about a double loop like this but when I hit a 2, I guess another loop should start to check for the surrounding but I am completely stuck...

```
for(i=0;i<lenght;i++){
   for(j=0;j<lenght;j++){
      if(matrix[i][j]==2){
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

If any of you have tips, I woud like it very much!

 (yeah, I am quite a novice)

Thanks a lot,
purkinje

Comment: Can two `2` values be next to each other?  If so, do they count as being in the same island?  Do you care about squares that touch on their diagonals?

Comment: Note: `lenght` -> `length`.

Comment: Hint: `matrix[i+x][j-y]` for `x` in `-1,0,1` and y in `-1,0,1` omitting 0/0.

Comment: David is right.  How many islands are in `matrix={{2,1,0,1,0,1,0,2},{1,2,1,0,1,0,1,0},{0,1,3,1,3,1,3,1},{1,2,1,2,1,0,1,2},{0,1,3,2,3,1,3,1},{1,0,1,2,1,0,1,0},{0,1,3,1,3,1,3,1},{1,2,1,0,1,2,1,2}}`  It could be 3, 5, or 7 depending on the answers to David's comment.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to look for a 3x3 tile like this:

```
x,x,x
x,2,x
x,x,x
```

Then I think you're on the right track.

You will never have an island 2 on the very edge, so you can limit your search to `[1,length-1]`. The following untested code factors out the actual check into its own function, which reduces the nested loops and makes it easier to read.

```
int is_island(int x, int y) {
    if (x <= 0 || y <= 0 || x >= length-1 || y >= length-1) {
        return 0; // bounds check
    }

    if (matrix[x][y] == 2) {
        int i,j;
        for (i=x-1; i<x+1; i++) {
            for (j=y-1; j<y+1; j++) {
                if ((i != x && j != y) && matrix[i][j] != 2) {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void look_for_islands() {
    for (i=1; i<length-1; i++){
        for (j=1; j<length-1; j++){
           if (is_island(i,j)) {
              printf("found island at %d,%d\n", i, j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `is_island()` function includes a bounds check. There are two reasons for this: first, an island can never occur in an edge row; and second, stepping outside the array bounds can result in unpredictable results or crashes. The check is not strictly necessary in this code snippet since they caller limits the bounds, but it is good practice and make the function reusable.

Comment: Have you actually tried your code? I think there are some problems with it. For example the fact that the while loop condition in `is_island` should be `i <= x + 1`. There is also the problem that you return `true` from the function as soon as a neighbor unequal to 2 is encountered.

Comment: Nope I said it was untested. The OP was completely stuck and I was trying to show an approach, not so much working code.

Answer (score 0):

There are some points you should probably clarify in your question as [David Grayson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28128) pointed out in the comments. In this answer I'm taking some guesses and hope that it solves your problems anyway. You need to include `<stdbool.h>` for the following two functions.

### Function `island_exists()`

This function contains your code (but slightly modified) and calls `is_island()`. Elements on the edge of the matrix are not checked, so the function is only going to check these elements:

```
. . . . . . . .
. o o o o o o .
. o o o o o o .
. o o o o o o .
. o o o o o o .
. o o o o o o .
. o o o o o o .
. . . . . . . .
```

As soon as an island is found, the function will return `true`. If the function doesn't encounter an island, it returns `false` in the end.

```
/* check if matrix contains island */
bool island_exists(int height, int width, int matrix[height][width])
{
    for (int y = 1; y < height - 1; ++y) {
        for (int x = 1; x < width - 1; ++x) {
            if (is_island(height, width, y, x, matrix))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

### Function `is_island()`

When calling this function, the coordinates `x` and `y` of the element to check are passed. It checks the surrounding elements as described by [tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189) in the comments.

```
/*
 * check if element is an island
 * precondition: (0 < y < height - 1) && (0 < x < width - 1)
 */
bool is_island(int height, int width, int y, int x, int matrix[height][width])
{
    if (matrix[y][x] != 2)
        return false;

    for (int i = y - 1; i <= y + 1; ++i) {
        for (int j = x - 1; j <= x + 1; ++j) {
            if (matrix[i][j] != 1 &&
                matrix[i][j] != 3 &&
                (i != y || j != x))
                return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

### Calling `island_exists()`

You can call the function `island_exists()` like this.

```
int matrix[8][8] = {{0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
                    {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
                    {0,1,3,1,3,1,0,1},
                    {1,0,1,2,0,3,1,0},
                    {0,1,3,1,3,1,0,1},
                    {1,0,1,2,1,0,1,0},
                    {0,1,3,1,3,1,0,1},
                    {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0}};

if (island_exists(8, 8, matrix)) {
    /* island exists in matrix */
} else {
    /* island does not exist in matrix */
}
```